# This code should refresh the screen. Please tell me where I am wrong

Tags: c++, winapi

As I understood, the `WriteConsole()` function writes an array of characters into the screen buffer. It works until I try to make a cycle.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main() {
    HANDLE hScreenBuffer;

    hScreenBuffer = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    char map[100];
    LPDWORD number_of_chars_to_write;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        map[i] = '#';
    }
    while (1) {
        
        WriteConsole(
            hScreenBuffer,
            map,
            100,
            number_of_chars_to_write,
            NULL

        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Invoke `WriteConsoleA` instead of `WriteConsole`.

Comment: Nothing changed

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues in your code:

First, as pointed in the comment, you need to use `WriteConsoleA` since you write narrow `char`s.

Second, you pass uninitialized pointer `LPDWORD number_of_chars_to_write;` to `WriteConsole`, that will likely cause a crash.

This is corrected code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main() {
    HANDLE hScreenBuffer;

    hScreenBuffer = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    char map[100];
    DWORD number_of_chars_to_write;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        map[i] = '#';
    }
    while (1) {
        WriteConsoleA(
            hScreenBuffer,
            map,
            100,
            &number_of_chars_to_write,
            NULL
        );
    }
}
```